# run RHEL9 docker container on centos 8 host

Tags: docker, rhel

My main developer box is running Centos8. I'm working on a project where I need to do some builds on RHEL7/8/9. I have docker installed on the host and pulling RHEL7 image from `registry.redhat.io/rhel7:7.9-702.1655292978`, RHEL8 from docker hub (`redhat/ubi8:latest`) and RHEL9 also from docker hub (`redhat/ubi9:latest`). RHEL 7/8 work without issue but RHEL9 has the error:

> subscription-manager is disabled when running inside a container.
> Please refer to your host system for subscription management.

I have a valid subscription but for some reason, it is not possible to actually run a RHEL9 image from a non RHEL host. I'm not sure I understand the reason for this but is there a workaround (other than changing the host to RHEL) so that I can register my RHEL9 container?

Comment: AFAIK that's just a warning. Does it actually stop you from doing things?

Comment: Yeah, it won't let me do anything - can't register etc

Comment: Do you have any success on this? Got to the same issue on macOS host.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky not yet. I just stuck with a RH9 host just now but will come back to it when I get some time. If I find a solution I'll post back here.

Comment: Thanks! On my side managed to workaround this using the Parallels VM instead of Docker.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky i've posted the solution now. I have my RHEL9 container running without issue on my centos box.

Comment: @incubus Thanks updating and sharing the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone in my team found a solution. The article https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5870841 basically points to injecting the subscription info (from a registered system) into the container.

Here is a sample docker file I used:

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/ubi9/ubi

COPY rhel9_sub/redhat.repo /run/secrets/redhat.repo
COPY rhel9_sub/rhsm /run/secrets/rhsm
COPY rhel9_sub/entitlement /run/secrets/etc-pki-entitlement
```

where the rhel9_sub folder I was copying from came from my registered RHEL9 host.

I can now query the repo and pull kernel packages into the container without issue.